# Woocommerce: Hide All Shipping Method When Choose Payment Gateway COD

Tags: javascript, php

anyone can help me, im try hide all shipping method when choose cod payment gateway but it's not working.

this my site pyorsihate.com

this PHP code:

```
// Enqueue the script on the checkout page
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_hide_all_shipping_script');

function enqueue_hide_all_shipping_script() {
    // Ensure it's the checkout page
    if (is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('hide-all-shipping-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/hide-all-shipping.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
```

This JS Code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // On page load
    checkPaymentMethod();

    // On payment method change
    $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function() {
        checkPaymentMethod();
    });

    function checkPaymentMethod() {
        // Check if COD is chosen
        if ($('#payment_method_cod:checked').length > 0) {
            // Hide all shipping methods
            $('ul.shipping_methods').hide();
        } else {
            // Show all shipping methods
            $('ul.shipping_methods').show();
        }
    }
});
```

If someone can help me, im try to many option, choose ID and hide all shipping it's still not working.

Hide All Shipping Method when choose payment method Cash On delivery (COD)